# Why does time per task in GridSearchCV increase during estimation?

Tags: grid-search, gridsearchcv

When running GridSearchCV, the time per task seems to be increasing:

[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYm9o.png)

Oviously, the first 11k take 95 mins, the next 11k take 135 minutes.

Why is that?

The inputs for GridSearchCV is just the estimator (RFC), param_grid, cross-validation via Stratified K fold, n_jobs=-1, scoring="accuracy" and verbose=True. That is, I have not included train_score which I suspect could have possibly increased the time per task because of continuous appending.

Comment: Welcome! Please include such text output as text in the question, rather than in a screenshot image. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks! I confirmed the edits now. Do you have an idea what might be the reason for this increase in time per task?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Your chance of finding someone helping you with that improves if you follow what I recommend in my previous comment. Please also have a careful look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. :D

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what the Stack Overflow community is and how it works.

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/conduct and https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

After you having posted your first question, I welcomed you to the community, edited your question to make it conform better to the guidelines (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as a help to you for improving the chances of you recieveing answers.

Please note that attacking me for editing your question and describing the motivations as "payment of the microboner" is strictly against the Code of Conduct.

Comment: U're right, thanks for the help. Pointing out the necessity of clarifying the meaning of a question that even you understood was very helpful. Im sorry you feel attacked, I didnt know you got a microboner out of it.. for everyone else, I found the answer, it has to do with how you mixed your parameter grid.